# how to add pinch zoom effect to the images parsed from web services and added on scrollview?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I have a scrollview and i added the images from webservice. Now i want to add pinch zoom effect to the images. But when i am going to zoom in image becomes full in size and exception is throwing NSRangeException.So guys please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use following method in your code to allow zoom -

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      return [self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
  }
```

Comment: I have tried your code.But it is not working actually i am returning imageview which is added in scrollview from this method.I think there will be poroblem with the framing scrollview but i am not recognizing it.